# spring-data-jpa-rest: How to access EntityManager prior to use but after binding by OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

In the non-HAL/REST world, this is pretty easy:

1. register a servlet filter;
2. lookup the em holder in the TransactionSynchronizationManager
3. have at it.

It seems the authors of the JPA/REST modules have "gone of the rails" of how things used to be done in Spring.  Seems like there's no way to hook into the processing chain in a meaningful way.

I'm hoping that I'm just missing something and someone can shed a light, but after ~ 2 days of looking at examples and checking the code and trying was to get my own code invoked by the RestResource handlers, I'm not seeing that the framework was designed to actually allow it.

Pointers welcome.

Comment: I've happened upon the JpaContext interface and default implementation.  It does return an EntityManager... but an unbound one, there's no transaction context and thus I can't unwrap it to change the underlying implementations settings, which is my actual goal in this case.

Comment: I found a fall-back way to do this - inserting an OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter in the filter chain followed by a custom filter that changes the underlying (Hibernate session) object.  Since the JPA interceptor will find this entity manager this works, but feels... wonky to do it this way.

Comment: why not add your solution as an answer? Makes it obvious to others that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

First I created my own custom sub-class of OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.  This helps with the systems multi-tenant support.

Then I use Spring configuration to wire up the custom sub-class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebFilterConfig {

    private final Collection<String> urlPatterns;

    @Autowired
    @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
    public WebFilterConfig(@Nonnull RepositoryRestConfiguration rrconfig) {
        String basePath = rrconfig.getBasePath().toString();
        if (!basePath.endsWith("/")) {
            basePath = basePath + "/";
        }
        urlPatterns = Collections.singletonList(basePath + "*");
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean openEntityManagerInViewFilterRegistration() {
        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistration = new FilterRegistrationBean(new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter());
        // Consider leaving this unset and having this filter active on all requests
        filterRegistration.setUrlPatterns(urlPatterns);

        // Sometimes good to have this ordered before security...
        filterRegistration.setOrder(-1);
        return filterRegistration;
    }

    // Now add out custom filter to add multi-tenant support  
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean tenancyFilterRegistration() {
        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistration = new FilterRegistrationBean(new MultiTenantFilter());
        filterRegistration.setName("tenancyDatabaseFilter");
        filterRegistration.setUrlPatterns(urlPatterns);
//        filterRegistration.setDispatcherTypes(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));

        // This MUST be ordered after the OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
        filterRegistration.setOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE);
//        filterRegistration.setOrder(100);

        return filterRegistration;
    }

}
```